# svn: The specified baseline is not the latest baseline, so it may not be checked out

Tags: svn

I am facing a strange problem while performing a svn commit operation. On linux(suse), when I try to commit, svn fails and gives the following error.

```
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: The specified baseline is not the latest baseline, so it may not be checked out.
```

But when I try to commit the same thing on windows(I took a checkout of the repository on the windows xp using tortoise svn) it works.

Now I am totally confuse why SVN on linux is showing such a strange behavior? Is there any problem in the checkout I had on the linux? Or its some standard SVN problem?

**EDIT:** One more observation: I took another checkout on linux and guess what it works, which means there is some problem in my working copy but what?

Comment: Do you get any output when you `svn update` the broken working copy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`svn cleanup` did the trick for me.

Comment: not for me =( Any other ideas?

Comment: I remember that actually I did a `commit` from another checkout of the repository and then `svn cleanup` and `svn update`. After that it starts working again.

Comment: I've created a patch, erased the local code completely, re-checked-out the code and applied the patch, with the same results. Even with with cleanup between every step. At this point I'm trying with every thing you can get me.